# OneHotEncoding: working in one dataframe, not working in very, very similar dataframe (pyspark)

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, one-hot-encoding

I am applying a OneHotEncoding function to two very similar dataframes. The first dataframe is the following:
[image]

When I apply the one hot encoding, everything works fine:
[image]

However, when I apply the exact same function to this different, but very similar dataframe:
[image]

The following error occurs:

[image]

I don't understand why this happens, because dataframe 1 and 2 were both extracted from a previous dataframe (they work as a train and test df for a machine learning application). Both are pyspark.sql dataframes. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure the column "district" contains only integers in the second dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you can't sort a list containing `None` and integers. There is perhaps a `null` in your column, which causes the line `categories.sort()` to crash.

If you want to do ML with Spark, I'd suggest using pyspark.ml package, instead of writing your own one-hot encoder. For example, see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder).

Comment: I hadn't even noticed that because this data was supposed to have been treated before and wasn't supposed to have any missing values... thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that's the issue here? I don't see how a null in column A would cause .sort() on the values from column B to fail.

Comment: @couka maybe there is a null somewhere else in column B.

Comment: I applied this line ex_2 = ex_2.na.fill(0) and everything is working fine now. Thank you both!!

Comment: @mck Yes, that's my point. Thanks for updating the answer.